# SAS Check dynamically if a libname/table/column EXISTS and update a field on that table

Tags: sas

I have a table with library, table, column and a result flag.

| library | table | columnA | columnB | result_flg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| lib1 | tab1 | field1 |  |  |
| lib1 | tab2 |  | field4 |  |
| lib3 | tab3 | field3 | field5 |  |

If the field columns (A or B) not missing, then the goal its to check if that columns exist in that lib/table dynamically and update the result_flag field with true or false.

Whats the efficient approach?

Tks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an in-line SQL query to check if the column exists and make it a 1 if it exists and 0 if it does not. The shortcut `(boolean condition)` will automatically create this. You can use the `update` statement to update the table in place.

```
data have;
    input library$ table$ column$;
    datalines;
sashelp air air
sashelp air notexist
sashelp class .
sashelp class name
;
run;
```

```
proc sql;
     update have
         set result_flg = (upcase(column) IN 
                            (select upcase(name)
                             from dictionary.columns 
                             where    upcase(library) = upcase(libname) 
                                  AND upcase(table)   = upcase(memname)
                            )
                          )
         where NOT missing(column)
     ;
quit;
```

Comment: This will work but is slower than other methods.

Comment: You right Rezza, but since ive 2 columns to validade (columnA and columnB) i fell more confortable on the update method.

Comment: As that was in an edit, my answer did not factor that in and the answer is not quite correct, as you need to check both columns and then determine the flag.

Comment: you right, sorry